# How can I get a list with totals in sql stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get a result like this, in a single list.

```
TYPE    | subtype | Total
  A     | z       | 5
  A     | y       | 3
total A | NULL    | 8
  B     | i       | 6
total B | Null    | 6
```

How can I do this in a sql stored procedure?

Edit: I work in T-Sql for Sql server

Comment: There's no such thing as a "SQL" stored procedure. Each RDBMS has it's own procedural language. SQL is not a RDBMS it's a separate language. Can you please update your post with the correct RDBMS and it's procedural equivalent. For instance PL/SQL for Oracle and T-SQL for SQL Server.

Comment: Also, without some code your answer will be nigh on impossible to answer as this is nowhere near enough information to try to work out what you are doing. Is this in a select statement? A user defined type? A temporary table? How are you populating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for all kinds of SQL.

```
Select type, subtype, total from source
union all
Select type, 'Total', sum(total) from source group by type
order by type
```

If you have a specific kind of SQL there may be a more efficient solution